# The resource cannot be found.

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver

I know this is a very common issue here and elsewhere.

I have pretty much tried all suggested solutions here but none has resolved my problem.

Wandering if there is anything else to add that can help me resolve this issue.

We have classic ASP already running on this server which is on our DMZ.

I recently added a .NET web application with a different application pool from the classic ASP application pool.

Yet I keep getting this error:

**The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.**

The webserver is configured to run both http protocol and https:

The bindings are configured at the Default Web Site level as the following:

```
Type=https
IPAddress = Unassigned
Port = 443
```

hostname = domain.com == not the real domain for security.
Require Server Name indication = Checked

```
SSL Certificate = {certificatename}

IIS = 6.2
```

Does anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: Check your W3C logs to make sure you're hitting the server. In the logs you should see the path, make sure it is mapped to the path of the application. You can also see the port number, make sure there is a binding in place. Make sure it's an application and not just a virtual directory. Check permissions and rewrite rules. There are so many things it could be.

Comment: And depending on the requirements, it may not be a good idea to host a website in your own office/home. That's why there are hosting providers.

Comment: @JohnWu, thank you very much for your prompt response. Before your response, I tried to come back here to update the post to say that .net has same permissions as the classic ASP apps that work.

I have also checked the W3C logs. There are two logs, one says failedLogFiles and the other simply said Logs. I checked both and there is no indication that the app is hitting the server. Any ideas why it is not hitting the server and any suggested remedies to get it to hit the server?

Comment: @VDWWD, this servers, as indicated, are on DMZ, not hosted in our office or home. The other server I mentioned is also hosted on DMZ and it works just fine. Only difference between the two is one doesn't have classic ASP - the one that actually works.

Comment: So classic ASP works but ASP.NET doesn't work? Do you see the W3C traffic for the classic?

Comment: @JohnWu, yes, all of the classic ASP apps are hitting the server.

Comment: That is truly bizarre. I assume they are under the same domain name and IP address. If you can hit one you should at least be able to hit the other, even if you get an error. What is the difference in the URLs?

Comment: @JohnWu, no difference at all. It is really bizarre like you said

Comment: Can you reach the ASP.NET site from a browser located on the server itself?

Comment: Please keep updating your question by moving the new info in comments up.